# Angular can't find variable cache

Tags: angular, go, heroku, safari

My Angular app works fine on everything when I run it locally, but if I deploy it on Heroku - in a Go server, aot is disabled on angular build on Chrome and Opera - both on mobile, linux and osx - but it throws an error on safari:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Cache
```

When I have a closer look at the error, I suppose it is from my module providers. Because it takes me to:

```
 main-es2015[...].js

[...], IP, KM, {
            provide: Cache, // error
            useClass: KM,
            multi: !0
        }],
```

Corresponding app.module.ts part

```
providers: [
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true},
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptorService, multi: true},
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CachingInterceptor, multi: true},
    ApplicationStateService,
    CacheMapService,
    {provide: Cache, useClass: CacheMapService, multi: true}
  ],
```

Cache provider wasn't multi, made it multi but made no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a variable named:

```
declare var Cache: {prototype: Cache; new():Cache}
```

in `lib.dom.d.ts` file. I was using this variable instead of my `cache.ts` model. So silly of me...
 If you have a cache model too, put this at top of your *.module.ts file

```
import {Cache} from 'path-to-cache-file'
```